# -bash: /bin/ls: No such file or directory

Tags: bash

Hello I don't know where problem about this.
I want to use the command `ls`, but the terminal says it doesn't exist.
This is the screenshot. I logged in with root user.
[image]

Command with stat, the output at below:

```
root@ns1:~# stat /bin/ls
  File: `/bin/ls'
  Size: 39696       Blocks: 80         IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 802h/2050d  Inode: 2488208     Links: 1
Access: (0755/-rwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2013-08-27 21:00:59.825120536 +0700
Modify: 2010-09-22 01:32:55.000000000 +0700
Change: 2013-08-27 21:00:48.291368562 +0700

root@ns1:~# stat /
  File: `/'
  Size: 4096        Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 802h/2050d  Inode: 2           Links: 23
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2013-08-27 15:48:31.285959829 +0700
Modify: 2013-08-27 15:42:39.251379071 +0700
Change: 2013-08-27 15:42:39.251379071 +0700

root@ns1:~# stat /bin
  File: `/bin'
  Size: 4096        Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 802h/2050d  Inode: 392449      Links: 2
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2013-08-27 20:53:00.251389526 +0700
Modify: 2013-08-27 20:51:59.861361479 +0700
Change: 2013-08-27 20:51:59.861361479 +0700
```

Comment: @Node I just edit my question with output stat /bin/ls. Thanks

Comment: Can you run it by running `/bin/ls` (with the absolute path)?

Comment: @Oli output same when I type #/bin/ls -la (-bash: /bin/ls: No such file or directory)

Comment: Could you also post an stat of your / and your /bin?

Comment: @Node, Ijust edit with output stat / and stat /bin, thanks

Comment: Hm, what about "lsattr /bin/ls" - no idea for now sorry.

Comment: What's the result of "file /bin/ls" ? it might not be the ls you're looking for, although the chmod failure is very worrying...

Answer (score 2):

You should have a look at this question on serverfault, and ensure that you not got rooted. :/ HTH
https://serverfault.com/questions/10884/bin-ls-not-found-even-though-it-exists